# UITableView not reloading while reload from UIView subview in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, tableview, subview, reloaddata

Im sub viewing uiview in view controller now i have called web service in `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` method also response came while reloading with web service data tableView is not reloading. any idea thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check out this question, it will be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787480/refresh-table-view

Comment: [yourtblview reload]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify whether you have data when you reload UITableView. You can check this by putting breakpoint in numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSections method.